# Oracle Apex - How to check if all rows of an interactive grid have been deleted?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I would like to know how to check if all the rows of an interactive grid have been deleted.

Is there a way to check that programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I got an answer to this,hope this helps for those who are in need.
Fetch your grid info :
 var igrid = apex.region ("regionStaticID").widget().interactiveGrid("getViews", "grid");

{where regionStaticID is the interactive grid static id}

if(igridL.model._numInsertedRecords === 0)
    {
                   // do whatever you want here when there are no rows in the grid
    }
```